# What is this under-seat part on a '99 GMC Sierra, and can it be repaired?

Tags: gmc, seat, sierra

This part of the driver's side broke off so the left side of the seat collapses a few inches down on that side. It's part of the seat power height system so I'm guessing a 'seat-height adjuster'?  It seems to ride inside the floor rails, so maybe also be part of the mechanism that powers the seat forward and backward. Maybe just called an 'undercarriage'? Unfortunately, I can't find anything like that. Looking at online parts diagrams I can't distinguish what it actually is.

More importantly, can I fix it or do I need a new one? It's an old beat-up truck I drive maybe once a month in-town so I don't care if it's a "there I fixed it" repair. However, my much-shorter wife drives it twice a year and always complains about the right-ward tilt and seat height so I need to do something about it.

It rotates a bit on the rod when going up and down, so j-b weld won't work (my first idea). I'd really like to just somehow re-attach it to the bottom half. Just lifting it back on doesn't work; it bounces off after the first bump and my wife falls over to the right. The rod is attached to the rest of it with rivets so I'm thinking I have to replace the entire whatever it is. Most seat parts from '99 are discontinued so I may have to try a junkyard. A repair would probably be a day's work shorter than a replacement.

**What is it, and can I repair it or must I replace it?**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It would need to be welded. Much lower cost to get one at a salvage yard. I am sure there is no demand so it should be cheap if you can remove it yourself. I added a few power seats to GM  cars from the 60's by changing the seat frames. Most were interchangeable and cheap doing the work yourself.

Comment: Agree with getting it from a wrecking yard. GM made ***MILLIONS*** of these trucks from 99-2007, both Chevrolet and GMC, which should have the same seat rails. Worst part about welding these is more than likely the weld will create a stress point which will fail again.

Comment: Good answer. But what is it called? What would I ask for when I call the yard?

Comment: I was thinking of the whole undercarridge of the seat. Maybe the days of go in and remove your own part are over ?